# How to dump only request and response JSON body with mitmdump?

Tags: http-proxy, mitmproxy

Now I can dump all request and response with mitmdump. I am using the following command :

```
mitmdump -w outfile.txt
```

And this command dumps all requests and responses but I want to dump only response and request JSON bodies. How can I do that? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this `mitmdump -dd > outfile`.If you need only headers and not the content then try `mitmdump -d > outfile`.

Comment: think "-dd" option is now gone -- v5.2.